# Soundcloud authentication/connection javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, soundcloud

```
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
// initialize client with app credentials
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'bea6b4a2c1108a4cfa99f0d40966108a',
  redirect_uri: 'http://www.samplewars.com/'
});

// initiate auth popup
SC.connect(function() {
  SC.get('/me', function(me) { 
    alert('Hello, ' + me.username); 
  });
});
</script>


Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://samplewars.com/soundcloud/ from frame with URL http://www.samplewars.com/soundcloud/?code=77c9dc160d723a52f67d42a89067848e&state=SoundCloud_Dialog_80886#access_token=1-26934-195352-78151464de9a2ec39&scope=non-expiring. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

I'm getting this error in my chrome console, and in FF it just keeps looping through the allow process without shooting out the alert.

Funny thing is, it worked for a second, then I went to get a drink, came back, and it was broken.

edit: it also stays inside of the popup as opposed to closing back to the original window
edit 2: it ALSO actually adds the permissions inside of soundcloud in the connect menu for the app. Just doesn't spit out the alert.

Edit 3: Okay, it works in FF now after I added an onclick event to stop it from constantly looping through the js. so now the code is:

```
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
// initialize client with app credentials
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'bea6b4a2c1108a4cfa99f0d40966108a',
  redirect_uri: 'http://www.samplewars.com/'
});

// initiate auth popup
function connectSC(){
SC.connect(function() {
  SC.get('/me', function(me) { 
    alert('Hello, ' + me.username); 
  });
});
}
</script>
<div id="connect_button" onClick="connectSC()">
connect to soundcloud
</div>
```

Which works in FF, but not in Chrome or IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting factor. I found the issue, if you try to connect using an URL without www. as the prefix, it won't work. Soundcloud must require it in order to build the token