# Soundcloud auth popup callback.html never closes after connecting

Tags: javascript, oauth, popup, soundcloud

I'm using [Soundclouds JS sample code for client side JS apps](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#client-side) to connect with the Soundcloud API, as a start.  The only difference between their code and mine is I've put in my own client_id and redirect_uri.  (I also copied their callback.html, put it on my server, put its address in the soundcloud page for my app).

After ok-ing with my popup blocker, the auth popup comes up and asks permission to access my account, I give it permission, then the popup clears all previous content and simply informs: 'This popup should automatically close in a few seconds' - but it doesn't, and the rest of the code that shows its past authorization never displays.

Here is Soundclouds sample that I'm using.  I've tried it while using a server on localhost and also deploying it and changing redirect_uri appropriately with the exact same results.

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',   // changed it to mine
  redirect_uri: 'http://example.com/callback'  
});

SC.connect().then(function() {
  return SC.get('/me');
}).then(function(me) {
  alert('Hello, ' + me.username);
});
```

Looking in the dev console on both Chrome and Firefox, I dont see any errors.  I've also made sure the protocol for my redirect_uri file matches between my account settings and the code.

Does the 'Website of your app' field on the Soundcloud page for my app make a difference?   I tried setting it, it didnt fix it.  What does client secret do?

The closest to an answer I've found so far is from [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310896/soundcloud-authentication-connection-javascript-issue) where it seems he found out that you can't use an url that doesn't start with 'www.' ???  Its hard for me to believe that this is the problem and unfortunately for me neither localhost or my domain start with www.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. The nearest I've got to finding a reason for the problem can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120534/window-opener-is-null-after-redirect). Unfortunately, this doesn't help, because it says that `window.opener` is removed when you navigate to a different domain, which the popup does in order to authenticate via `soundcloud.com`. The question is then "how do soundcloud suggest you use `window.opener` when you've gone to a different domain?"

Comment: have you found any solution yet. I am also facing the exact same problem.

Comment: SoundCloud's sample code is broken. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34224244/769262).

Answer (score 0):

In your callback.html, change the line:

```
<body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
```

to:

```
<body onload="window.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
```

In your application setup page at soundcloud.com, ensure your website setting and callback uri are on the same domain (whether that is localhost or the production domain) and all should work.

Note: for debugging, comment out this line to leave the popup there deliberately, then console can be used to interrogate other code in the callback.html page.